# Angularfire with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

I am using angularjs and angularfire in my application. Therefore, I have written a service and everything is working fine.

However, this is written in JavaScript and I am currently trying to rewrite my code in TypeScript and am looking for the Typescript definition for angularfire.

The one from [definetely typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularfire/angularfire.d.ts) is looking pretty old. Can I use the definitions from [angularfire2](https://angularfire2.com/api/) in an older Angular Version than Angular2?

Comment: When you install angularfire2 via npm, it should come with all the necessary definition files such as `angularfire2.d.ts`, `interfaces.d.ts`, `tokens.d.ts`, etc under `node_modules/angularfire2`.

Comment: Try `npm install @types/angularfire`.